# Configurar sql server sem instância

Tags: sql-server

Utilizo SQL Management Studio para execução de queries e na instalação foi configurado para utilizar com INSTÂNCIA.

Como faço para retirar essa instância da configuração ou utilizar uma padrão? A instância que eu tenho configurada é SQLEXPRESS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não existe. O SQL Server trabalha com instâncias, **sempre**.

Para se conectar ao banco sem precisar usar o nome da instância, pode-se definir uma instância para atender as requisições direto no IP da máquina.

1. Abra o **SQL Server configuration Manager**
2. Expanda o nó **Configurações de rede do SQL Server**
3. Clique em **Protocolos para [nome da instância] (SQL Express, neste caso)**
4. No painel a direita, clique em **TCP/IP** e ative-o.
5. Depois abra **Propriedades** e entre na aba **Endereços IP**
6. Vá para a seção **IP AII**
7. Defina **Portal TCP** como a porta que o SQL Server está usando (padrão 1433)
8. Certifique-se que o campo **Portas TCP Dinâmicas**  está **em branco**
9. Reinicie o SQL Server.

Agora a instância **SQL Express** do SQL Server irá atender às requisições feitas ao IP da sua máquina, mesmo que não seja especificado o nome da instância.

Então, será possível conectar usando apenas **localhost**, **127.0.0.1**, **.** ou **NomeComputador**.